# Autologin question with LightDM & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, login, lightdm, autologin

I have set up a batch of workstations at a library using DRBL. These workstations are running Ubuntu 14.04. I want these workstations to autologin to a specific user (a different one for each workstation, since the `/home` file system is NFS mounted). I have a custom copy of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` for each workstation and I have set `autologin-user-timeout=30` and `autologin-user=workstationuser` (different for each workstation). This mostly works, but there are some 'weirdnesses' I would like to resolve.

1. Doing a Shutdown from the gear menu and then restarting the machine does not always log the user in. Sometimes it behaves like the user 'locked' the screen and it is expecting to unlock a running session. I want a shutdown to imply a full logout (it is too much to ask the library staff people to logout and then shutdown). Always. These are guest accounts, so there is never a session to save (screen locking is also disabled).
2. Doing a logout from the gear menu brings up the list of all possible users. This is OK (sometimes someone wants or need to login as a 'real' user). But if the login screen is left alone and/or after the 'real' user logs out, it does not automagically re-login to the autologin-user. What do I need to do to fix this?

I am not very experienced with Ubuntu -- I am an old hand with CentOS and RedHat.

Comment: Things have changed somewhat. Mainly in location of files involved. Before digging further try new (proper) locations and files:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: @zika suggests "Before digging further try new (proper) locations and files: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM"